# Keyboard hidden at change focus from UICollectionViewCell to UISearchController keyboard tvOS

Tags: swift2, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uikeyboard, tvos, uisearchcontroller

We are implementing the `UISearchController` in tvOS application. While we get the data from the search operation. The data shows in to the `UICollecionViewCell`. While we goes (with focus) from `UICollectionViewCell` to `UIKeyboard` then the focus move to UITabBar.
While we want focus go to UIKeyboard.
This problem get on slow scroll.

[image]

While we want like this image. When we move fast to upper direction the `UIKeyboard` shows.
[image]